# react-native-image-slider (cannot display local images)

Tags: javascript, react-native

My local images don't display when using react-native-image-slider

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
    View,
    Text,
    StyleSheet,
    Button,
    Image,
    TouchableHighlight
} from "react-native";
import ImageSlider from 'react-native-image-slider';

class HomeScreen extends Component {

    render() {          
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>         
        <View style={{alignItems: 'center'}}>                   
            <ImageSlider
                    loopBothSides
                autoPlayWithInterval={3000}
                images={[
                    '../assets/img/art_1.png',
                    '../assets/img/art_2.png',
                    '../assets/img/art_3.png',          
                ]}  
                style={{width:200, height: 200}}
            />              
        </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
export default HomeScreen;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'center'
    }
});
```

The only things that appears on the screen are the circle icons that tell you what image it's currently displaying. The images themselves are not displayed.

Answer (score 2):

For local image, use `require`;

```
images={[
  require('../assets/img/art_1.png'),
  require('../assets/img/art_2.png'),
  require('../assets/img/art_3.png'),          
]}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping out. I'm still getting the same error, unfortunately. Do you think it could be a dependency issue? I only installed the package with "yarn add react-native-image-slider"

Comment: This is where I referenced it from:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-image-slider

Comment: If you check the source code (line 193), the accepted images are either uri string or image's `require`. Make sure that the path to the images is correct (relative to the executing script's path).

Comment: I managed to get it to work with a different package, react-native-image-slider-show.

   dataSource: [
        {
          title: 'Title 1',
          caption: 'Caption 1',   
          url: require("../assets/img/art_1.png"),
        },
      ],

I couldn't get the old package to work properly. I was wondering though, which file were you referring to about the URI string on line 193?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<Image source={item} style={styles.customImage} resizeMode={'contain'} />

- instead of -

<Image source={{ uri: item }} style={styles.customImage} />
```

---

```
const profileSlider = [
    // 'https://placeimg.com/640/640/nature',
    // 'https://placeimg.com/640/640/people',
    // 'https://placeimg.com/640/640/animals',
    // 'https://placeimg.com/640/640/beer',
    require('../images/slider/animals.png'),
    require('../images/slider/beer.png'),
    require('../images/slider/nature.png'),
    require('../images/slider/people.png'),
];
```

Answer (score 0):

### Try this one

```js
dataSource = {
  [{
      url: require('../assets/img/RPImages/RP111_1.jpg')
    },
    {
      url: require('../assets/img/RPImages/RP111_2.jpg')
    },
  ]
}
```

Comment: Welcome Vivek, You need to explain more your answer to help better who need your help ok? explain your code and what are you thinking to post a answer like this, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I understand that the question was a very long time ago, it will help someone.

According to the documentation, the easiest way to use a slider is like this:

```
<ImageSlider 
data={[
    {img: 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ5a5uCP-n4teeW2SApcIqUrcQApev8ZVCJkA&usqp=CAU'},
    {img: 'https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/environment-earth-day-hands-trees-growing-seedlings-bokeh-green-background-female-hand-holding-tree-nature-field-gra-130247647.jpg'},
    {img: 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/19/08/32/marguerite-729510__340.jpg'}
]}
autoPlay={false}
onItemChanged={(item) => console.log("item", item)}
closeIconColor="#fff"/>
```

But if you want to use local images you have to use 'require' and property localimg in slider, like this:

```
<ImageSlider 
data={[
    {img: require('./img/someImg1.jpg')},
    {img: require('./img/someImg2.jpg')},
    {img: require('./img/someImg3.jpg')}
]}
autoPlay={false}
localImg
onItemChanged={(item) => console.log("item", item)}
closeIconColor="#fff"/>
```